# Linq query for one to many

Tags: linq

My question involves MVC + Linq query. I will try to make it simple without going into the details of the Model, View, etc..  Say I have 2 tables T1 & T2. T1 holds restaurants details & T2 holds restaurants image paths. T2 rows contain restaurantID. Now if T2 has more than one rows of image paths for a Restaurant and I only need the first image path from T2 in the linq query how would I form such query? I tried to simplify the question as in fact I have 6 table joins related to the Restaurants in the query. I formed a view model which only contains the fields I want to display. I am trying to populate the view model in the controller & the query is in the controller obviously.

When I join T2 to the query, I get all the Restaurants details together with the images. But the view repeats the same Restaurant  as many times as the number of table rows in T2 which is not what I want. This is the problem from the way I set the query. The query uses joins. I only need the first row from T2 while I get all from the Restaurant details. I failed to find an example for such requirement on the web so far. Your directions will be much appreciated.

Serhat Albayoglu

Comment: Your question is not very clear

Answer (score 0):

On your join you can use an `into` and then in the select you can select the `FirstOrDefault`

```
var query = from t in context.T1
            join t2 in context.T2 on t.Id equals t2.RestaurantID into tgroup
            select
            {
              t2.FirstOrDefault().path
            };
```